# When to use virtual data member in class?

Tags: c#

I know what the use of virtual methods is, and how to declare them. But my question is: When should I declare a property as virtual?

For example:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual string lastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check out  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx

Comment: when you have multiple children with different or slightly different behavior.

Comment: As the matter of fact, *property* is just a syntactic sugar, since both `get` and `set` a methods; so the rules are the same

Comment: anyone can answer me with simple example so i can understand it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As comments below this question state, **data members are in fact methods**, so you can declare them as *virtual*.

With properties you can add some validation later on, or implement events, for example when you implement *INotifyPropertyChange* interface.

Code from MSDN:

```
class MyBaseClass
{
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}


class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
  private string name;

 // Override auto-implemented property with ordinary property
 // to provide specialized accessor behavior.
  public override string Name
  {
      get
      {
          return name;
      }
      set
      {
          if (value != String.Empty)
          {
              name = value;
          }
          else
          {
              name = "Unknown";
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rules are the same, since *property* is, generally speaking, a syntactic sugar to hide `get` and `set` methods:

```
  public class Base {
    public virtual string LastName {
      get; // this is method (.Net implements it for you)
      set; // this is method (.Net implements it for you)
    }
  }
```

Imagine

```
  Base b = ...
  ...
  b.LastName = b.LastName + "x";
```

and compare, please, with Java which *doesn't have* properties:

```
  b.setLastName(b.getLastName() + "x");
```

For the class in the question you may want to implment something like this:

```
  public class Derived: Base {  
    public override string LastName {
      get {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(base.LastName)
          ? base.LastName
          : base.LastName.ToUpper(); 
      } 
      set {   
        if (null == value)
          throw new ArgumentNullException("value")

        base.LastName = value;
      }
    }
```